# Script gets error when VBE isn't open

Tags: vba, excel

The following procedure is called when a button is pressed. It is supposed to add a new worksheet and rename (codename) the worksheet object/module. This needs to be renamed because another procedure later will add code to the worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Add_OrderForms()
    Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Order Forms"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets("Order Forms").CodeName).Name = "OrderForms"

End Sub
```

However, if the VB editor is not open, I get a run time error 9: subscript out of range. I don't get this error when I have the editor open. But the customer will not have the editor open. Should I be declaring any variables first?

Comment: Have you tried, `...VBComponents(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Forms")...`?

Comment: I just did, replaced the third line in the Sub with ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Forms").CodeName).Name = "OrderForms" and got the same error. Would I need to declare variables for the project and components?

Comment: It may be a simple timing error. Add a couple of `DoEvents` lines after renaming the sheet and before changing the codename.

Comment: @Rory could you show me what you mean? I added `DoEvents` after renaming the sheet. I am still unfamiliar with using `DoEvents`.

Comment: @gadgeyoz I've posted what I meant as an answer, with an alternative suggestion. I'm not personally a fan of trying to alter a project that is running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the project when it's locked for viewing. When the VBE is open, you have manually unlocked it and that's why it works. But when it's closed, it's locked again.

You can remove the protection and it will work as written. You probably don't want to do that, so here's an alternative. Create the sheet with the codename you want and save it. Then instead of a creating a new sheet, copy that sheet into your workbook. I called my workbook with the Order Form sheet Book3.xlsx

```
Public Sub Add_OrderForms()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Book3.xlsx")
    wb.Worksheets(1).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    wb.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: This wouldnt work for me because this workbook is going to be sent to people (blank) and they will fill it out. However, I did sort of what you suggested by adding the blank worksheet into the workbook with the codename 'OrderForms' (worksheet.name is 'TEMPLATE-blank') and then copied it. When it is copied, the new one is named 'OrderForms1' so I can just reference that throughout my procedures.

Comment: `Private Sub Add_OrderForms()
    OrderForms.Copy after:=Sheets(1)
    With Sheets("TEMPLATE-blank (2)")
        .Visible = True
        .Name = "Order Forms"
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub`

Comment: This answer is exactly what I've come up with for a similar situation I have, with an Excel "application" that uses three types of workbook, all locked and with their VB locked too. I'd not found the suggestion anywhere else, so came looking for unanswered questions to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Add_OrderForms()
    Debug.Print Activeworkbook.VBProject.Name
    Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Order Forms"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets("Order Forms").CodeName).Name = "OrderForms"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was suggesting this:

```
Private Sub Add_OrderForms()
    Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Order Forms"
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets("Order Forms").CodeName).Name = "OrderForms"

End Sub
```

If that still doesn't work, I'd suggest application.ontime:

```
Private Sub Add_OrderForms()
    Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Order Forms"
    Application.Ontime Now(), "UpdateOrderCodename"

End Sub
```

In a normal module:

```
Public Sub UpdateOrderCodename()
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets("Order Forms").CodeName).Name = "OrderForms"
End Sub
```

Comment: This code sits in a normal module since the worksheet module is being created when the button is clicked. Before it runs this procedure however, it deletes the old worksheet module that was created. The user can only have one order form so the new one will overwrite the old. I did somethign similar to what Dick said.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, a cheap shortcut is to open the VBE via code then close it again. While the user will see a quick flash of the VBE, it still accomplishes your goal.

```
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets("Order Forms").CodeName).Name = "OrderForms"
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
```